# How to convert int[][] to Mat in opencv Java?

Tags: java, arrays, opencv, mat

I got a function where i process different arrays[][] and I need to use a Mat because I'm working with images, so I need the pixels of that image.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(imagelocation);
```

I need a way to get the pixels values of that Mat.
But I was wondering if I can convert an array[][] into a Mat.
I hope you understand and help me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the pixel values of the Mat you can use: [reference](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html)

```
Mat m;
int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
double pixelValue = m.get(0, 0) // get pixel at row 0, column 0
```

To convert an array to Mat:

```
byte[] raw_data = ...;
Mat mat = new Mat();
mat.put(0, 0, raw_data);
```